# Можно ли объявлять переменные внутри ветвлений

Tags: c++

В общем задание: Создать массив, выкинув из исходного элементы расположенные между мин и макс. И вот я создаю массив размером, исходя от индекса минимального и максимального. Начальный массив содержит 10 элементов. Но создаю новый массив в условии. И далее хочу вывести его в цикле. Но мне выдаёт ошибку "B was not declared in this scope" Вопрос такой почему нельзя объявлять в условии?[image: фото]

Comment: В С++ не допускаются встроенные массивы, чей размер не является константой времени компиляции. Так что то что вы делаете - это уже не С++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете объявить переменную внутри блока. В этом случае её область видимости ограничена этим блоком.

Если вам нужно работать с переменной вне блока, объявляйте её также вне блока.

---

В вашем случае массив `B` обявляется внутри `if`-блоков, соответственно они только внутри этих блоков и видны. Если бы это было не так, подумайте, что должно было бы произойти с таким кодом:

```
if (false)
{
    int B[10];
}
B[0] = 0;
```

---

С стандарте C++ массивы должны иметь константный размер. Ваш компилятор (gcc?) может разрешать и неконстантный размер, но чтобы ваш код работал на любом компиляторе, имеет смысл подумать о динамической аллокации или об использовании `std::vector`.

Comment: Дак а как я её объявлю, мне ведь нужен размер, а размер зависит от условия

Comment: @m1zl-s, тогда используйте `std::vector` или указатель на память, выделенную в куче с помощью `new`. Первое предпочтительнее.

Comment: @m1zl-s: Вы ж программист! Подсчитайте сначала размер в зависимости от условия, потом объявляйте.

Answer (score 3):

Начнем с того, что все же стандарт C++ не позволяет определять массивы с размером, не известным во время компиляции... так что тут надо либо не мелочиться и использовать массив заведомо достаточный, либо выделять его динамически, либо использовать что-то типа `std::vector`...

А во-вторых, имя ограничено блоком, так что вижу у вас только то, что массивы в разных блоках `if` с одним именем - на самом деле разные массивы, и что во втором блоке после объявления нет точки с запятой :) Естественно, что за пределами блоков `B` не виден (кстати, если бы был виден - то ответьте: какой брать - из первого блока или из второго?)

Вы бы дали минимальный пример, и текстом, а не картинкой - было бы о чем говорить, а так...

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле этот вопрос очень тонкий. Как верно уже отметили - можно создавать переменную внутри операторного блока. Но на самом деле, в случае со switch/case разные версии компилятора могут вести себя по-разному.

Comment: И каком же "могут вести себя по-разному" идет речь?